# Azure Durable Function - final retry logic

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I'm building a durable function and I need to create some kind of alert if the activity fails after the `maxNumberOfAttempts`

When debugging, I see that the DurableOrchestrationContext class has a property called `History`, but I cannot access that since it is internal.

At this point the only option I can think of is to use Azure Monitor to group/summarize the logs by ExecutionId.  I dislike that approach since Azure Monitor shouldn't know or care about the `maxNumberOfAttempts` configured in the function.

Is there some other way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: When retrying did not result in any succesfull call to the function a `FunctionFailedException` is thrown. That one should be logged and you can create an alert based on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out with the information @peter-bons gave:

> When retrying did not result in any successful call to the function a
> `FunctionFailedException` is thrown.

Here is a sample of the code below:

```
[FunctionName("MyDurableFunctionOrchestrator")]
public async Task RunOrchestrator(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context, ILogger log)
{
    var retryOptions = new RetryOptions(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), 2)
    {
        BackoffCoefficient = 2
    };

    var request = context.GetInput<UserRequest>();         

    var tasks = new List<Task>
    {
        context.CallActivityWithRetryAsync(nameof(Example1Activity), retryOptions, request),
        context.CallActivityWithRetryAsync(nameof(Example2Activity), retryOptions, request)
    };

    try
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }            
    catch(FunctionFailedException e)            
    {
        // Azure Monitor will alert on this
        log.LogError(e, "Critical Error: {identity}", request.Identity);
        
        // this will tell us all the tasks that failed
        foreach(var task in tasks.FindAll(t => t.IsFaulted))
        {                    
            log.LogError(task.Exception, "Failed activity for '{identity}'", request.Identity);    
        }                
    }
}
```